# HttpURLConnection output to byte array then to String

Tags: java

I'm reading a response from an HttpURLConnection object to a String like so:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = ...;
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    conn.getInputStream());

StringBuilder sb = ...;
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}

String asString = sb.toString();
```

If I want to read instead to a byte array first, then convert that byte array to a String, what's the right way to do it?

```
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(16384);
byte[] buf = new byte[512];
while (true) {
    int len = in.read(buf);
    if (len == -1) {
        break;
    }
    baos.write(buf, 0, len);
}

byte[] out = baos.toByteArray();

// as a string:
String asString = new String(out);
```

but I'm not specifying the character in either case - are the two String outputs at the end of the examples equivalent?

Thanks

Comment: Note that your first snippet skips new line characters. Also, you probably want to specify character sets.

Comment: Yes, but both are wrong (I guess), because you are ignoring the encoding.

Comment: Ok, how would I know the encoding though - does it come back in the response?